# Ball attached to string snaps in decelerating car

Tags: forces, acceleration

A ball hanging from the ceiling in a decelerating car will make an angle. What happens if the string snaps while the car is decelerating? As gravity is the only force acting on the ball after the string snaps, is my assumtion that the ball will fall straight down correct?

Answer (score 1):

The ball has forward momentum and will keep going with constant speed forward. At the same time, gravity will accelerate it downwards so it will start moving downwards as will.

From the outside this will look like a arch that gets tighter and tighter since the forward speed is constant and the downward speed is increasing.

How this looks from inside the car depends on what the car is doing. If the car keeps decelerating, the ball will move forward relative to the car until it hits something.